# javascript power of 0 odd result?

Tags: javascript, exponent

im using chrome 
with this code:

```
var startbet = 1;
var shot = 0;
var bet = startbet * 2^shot;
```

n^0=n in this case
it should be equal to 1 regardless of n

is this an error with javascript or do some people beleive to the power of 0 should be handled diffrently?

Comment: What does "n^0=n in this case" mean? You haven't said anything about `bet`, `startbet` or `shot`. You need to clarify your question - at the moment it's unanswerable.

Comment: What is the value of `startbet` and what is the end value of `bet` that you're getting?

Comment: @Jon Skeet  2^0=2, 3^0=3, 4^0=4, i thought ^ meant 'to the power of' like in the windows calculator

Comment: @user1693548: You mean that's the Javascript behaviour - it wasn't clear what you *expected* vs what the *actual* behaviour was.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Javascript, the `^` operator is [bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Bitwise_operators), not exponent.

As Mikhail says, you have to use [Math.pow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) to compute exponents.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to use [Math.pow](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp) instead